# Verilog XOR operation with "z" input

Tags: verilog

Say, I have a 4 bit test_expr formed by concatenating 4 1b input ports. The input port corresponding to the LSB of test_expr is connected at TB top with a wire but the wire is undriven.

I have an assert that fires if(^test_expr === 1'bx). I am using Synopsys VCS and Verdi to simulate my design.

Now when i pull out the test_expr in verdi, i see a "z" on LSB. And my assert also fires.

Does this mean that XOR operation with a "z" bit **always** gives out an "x"? Or is this something that is simulator dependent and can vary?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xor operation gives an output of **x** when any of the inputs is **z**. Please find the truth table for the basic gate operations [here](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_7iSe0IE7ItA/R4rsLuxBVKI/AAAAAAAAAlA/Bon82qtZMWA/s400/tt1f.JPG). As Matthew Taylor has pointed out in a previous comment, that is logically the correct output for a floating input.
As to give an answer to your comment, Z means 'high impedance'. Hence when any of the inputs is not clear (be it an X or Z), we can only expect the result to be unknown 'x' and not 'z'.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that XOR operation with a "z" bit always gives out an "x"?

Yes. Inputs to logic gates must always be driven; a floating ("z") input to a gate will result in erroneous, unpredictable behavior ("x").

Comment: Because that is how real electronics behaves. If you left one input to an XOR gate unconnected, that input would float somewhere between Vss and Vdd and so would be unknown. If any input to an XOR gate is unknown then the output is unknown. (Think about it.)

Comment: I think the essence of question is misunderstood. I am not expecting output to be known if input is unknown. My doubt is if one of the inputs is "z" should output be "z" or "x" which are both unknowns but "z" output should not be caught with a === 1'bx comparison

Comment: The boolean operators in Verilog model real electronics. If one of the inputs to a real XOR gate were `z` then the output would be `x` not `z`. `x` means it's either a `1` (top transistor on, bottom off) or a `0` (bottom transistor on, top off), we don't know which. `z` means _high-impedance_ (both transistors off). The output of a real gate would never ever be `z` if one of its inputs were `z`, therefore the output of a Verilog boolean operator is never going to be `z`. Basically, `z` does not mean "unknown", it means "high impedance" (something completely different).

Comment: Okay! Makes perfect sense. Thanks Matthew